# Why was the Gryffindor Quidditch team flying outside the Quidditch pitch?

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts, the-crimes-of-grindelwald

At about an hour and seven minutes into the film *Fantastic Beasts: The Crimes of Grindelwald* the Gryffindor Quidditch team is seen flying in formation towards the Quidditch stadium in the background.

[image: Screenshot from film showing the team flying towards the stadium]

As far as I can tell from the books, Quidditch practice always takes place on the Quidditch pitch. The players don't fly all around the rest of the grounds.

Is there any particular reason why in this case the team would have been flying from somewhere else towards the stadium?

Comment: The _Fantastic Beasts_ movies all take place many years before Harry shows up at Hogwarts. Rules could easily change in the intervening decades. Also, the movies play a bit fast and loose with the books, so there's no real need for them to be consistent with a book that was never written.

Comment: For the same reason that, in my high school (lo these many decades ago), in my senior year they stopped allowing the football team & cheerleaders to wear their uniforms to class on game day, because the previous year the varsity vs. junior varsity cheerleaders got into an argument about who's allowed to wear what when. I.e. it's a special privilege accorded to the Quidditch players which must've led to problems at some point, so by Harry's day it wasn't done.

Answer (score 1):

The inclusion of players zooming by on brooms was a fun way to end a dramatic scene of triumph for the focal character. The Quidditch pitch is far from the school and having players in the distance wouldn't have been as exciting.

But reminding the audience of Quidditch may also be important for upcoming films. Responding to a 2018 interview with The Leaky Cauldron, series director David Yates says that the revisits are more than just fun:

> "I don’t think [Rowling] is really interested in repeating herself or leaning too much on the past. [...] Going back to Hogwarts is a very important function of this story, not a sort of way of appeasing the nostalgia factor of the series."

Later in the interview, he does seem to concede that the Hogwarts scenes also serve to reconnect viewers with the familiar world of Harry Potter.

> Yates said this decision actually came as a result of wanting to give 1920s Dumbledore a proper introduction, and *more of an idea of what to expect from the Hogwarts flashback scenes:*
>
> "It was something that evolved in the developing process. Because we
> were introducing Dumbledore, it felt right to *bring that world back
> into this one.* We’re there very briefly."

Whether the Quidditch players were simply for dramatic effect or will be important later is still unknown. In universe answer: Those were Seeker tryouts, and all the potential recruits were eager to catch a rogue Snitch.